# Banach space is separable iff Borel $\sigma$-algebra coincides with $\sigma$-algebra generated by open balls

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, banach-spaces

The question is essentially in the title.

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $\mathcal B(X)$ be a Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra generated by the collection of all open balls. Is it true that $X$ is separable $\Leftrightarrow$ $\Sigma=\mathcal B(X)$?

"If" ($\Rightarrow$) part is pretty straightforward and was already covered on this site numerous times: separability of $X$ implies that any open set is a union of at most countable number of open balls, so $\Sigma$ contains the whole topology of $X$ and, consequently, $\mathcal B(X)$.

I'm having trouble establishing the "if only" ($\Leftarrow$) part. My attempt was to assume $X$ to be non-separable, so we can construct an open set $U$ which is a union of uncountably many pairwise disjoint open balls of equal radius ([see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181226/if-any-open-set-is-a-countable-union-of-balls-does-it-imply-separability/)). It now seems reasonable to conclude that since $U$ can't be represented as a countable union of open balls *this means (?)* that $U\notin\Sigma$. But I'm not sure whether this is even true: for example, is complement of a point a countable union of open balls if $X$ is non-separable? In other words, is any open set in $\Sigma$ indeed a countable union of open balls?

I'd be glad for any hints for this question.

### Update (4th November, 2022)

Following some references from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32785/cyle-borele-for-e-non-reflexive-grothendieck-banach-space) on MathOverflow I've found [the article by D. H. Fremlin](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/hokkaido-mathematical-journal/volume-9/issue-2/Borel-sets-in-non-separable-Banach-spaces/10.14492/hokmj/1381758132.full) where a similar question was posed and answered for the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra $\hat{\mathcal C}(X)$ generated by the dual space $X'$. The following statement was proved there:

> $l^1(\aleph_1)$ is not separable, but $\mathcal B(l^1(\aleph_1))=\hat{\mathcal C}(l^1(\aleph_1))$.

More specifically, the following lemma was stated and proved:

> Lemma: If $X$ is an infinite set such that $2^{X\times X}=2^X\otimes2^X$, then $\mathcal B(l^1(X))=\hat{\mathcal C}(l^1(X))$. Here $\times$ denotes the Cartesian product and $\otimes$ denotes the [product of $\sigma$-algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Product_.CF.83-algebra).

Fremlin then refers to $2^{\aleph_1\times \aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1}\otimes2^{\aleph_1}$ as a known result in set theory (I assume in ZFC), but his reference had not yet appeared in print when this article came out, so I'd have to search for it separately.

All of this might be related to my question since $\Sigma$ can also be realised as a cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra. I've yet to read the proof of the Lemma and see whether it could be adapted to answer my question. I hope this update will be usefull for others when thinking about this problem.

Comment: A perhaps simpler way to think about the question is: if $X$ is a discrete metric space of cardinality $\aleph_1$, can every subset of $X$ be in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open balls?  If $2^{\aleph_1}>2^{\aleph_0}$ then the answer is no simply by a cardinality argument, so it is at least consistent with ZFC that this is impossible.

Comment: Or even more simply, you could ask: Can $P(\omega_1)$ be generated as a $\sigma$-algebra by only $\aleph_1$ elements?

Comment: @EricWofsey Isn't $\sigma$-algebra generated by open balls in discrete metric space is just the family of those sets that are either at most countable or their complement is at most countable? So unless $X$ is at most countable itself this is impossible? I'd also be glad if you could explain how this is related to my problem, unfortunately I'm not well versed in cardinals/ordinals.

Comment: Well, it depends on the metric.  For instance, you might have a discrete metric where the balls of radius $1$ are all singletons, but there are balls of radius $2$ that  are uncountable and have uncountable complement.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, I see. By "discrete metric" you mean any metric that induces discrete topology, right? I'm just used to thinking about "discrete metric" as specifically the one where all distances between any two distinct points are 1.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ok, I think I understand what you mean now. By non-separability of $X$ we have a subset $D$ of isolated points with cardinality at least $\aleph_1$. Now we look at $D$ as metric space induced by $X$. Then $D$ is discrete, $\Sigma\cap D$ is still $\sigma$-algebra generated by balls and $\mathcal B(X)\cap D$ is now just the powerset of $D$.

Comment: Right, that's the idea.  Although, I realize now it has a problem: the pullback of $\Sigma$ to a $\sigma$-algebra on $D$ could be larger than the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the balls of $D$, since there could be balls around points of $X$ whose intersection with $D$ is not a ball around any point of $D$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yeah, right, I now realise this too. So even if $\sigma$-algebra generated by the balls of $D$ doesn't coincide with $2^D$ we cannot claim the same for $\Sigma\cap D$.